# Phonegap + Wordpress + In-App purchases

Tags: ios, wordpress, cordova, in-app-purchase

I want to create a cross platform app , which will pull content from wordpress and display a list of posts. On selecting a post from the list it will display the full post.
The glitch is that few of these posts will be paid ones, meaning the full post can be read only after payment. 
According to Apple policies, i would have to implement an In-App purchase or my app will be rejected. My understanding is i can use my own payment gateway for other platforms.
I request suggestions to implement this correctly.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your asking ? 
Best way would be having Wordpress output xml or JSON data and creating your own UI in your app to show this. Then have a separate XML feed for paid content that can only be unlocked using an in-app purchase.

To do in-app purchases using Phonegap you will need the in-app purchase plugin.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins